# Swift application with webview and PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, jquery-mobile

i have created a jquery mobile website, and then i have created a swift app with web-viewer.
it works but on my website there are a PDF links, once from the IOS App a pdf link is clicked, it will open the pdf within the webview.

the problem is am not able to do a back action after the pdf is opened, i have tried to implement finger swipe ( left , right ) and it worked for all pages except the pdf.

how i can left the pdf downloaded instead of opening it on website or at least how i can implement any way to do a back action from the pdf.

```
     let swipeLeftRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
            let swipeRightRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
            swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = .left
            swipeRightRecognizer.direction = .right

            webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftRecognizer)
            webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightRecognizer)

@objc private func handleSwipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (recognizer.direction == .left) {
            if webView.canGoForward {
                webView.goForward()
            }
        }

        if (recognizer.direction == .right) {
            if webView.canGoBack {
                webView.goBack()
            }
        }
    }
```